# Primefaces fileDownload component not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces 5.1 I use fileDownload component to download xls from tomcat webapps folder but file download is not working.

**user.xhtml**

```
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
    <p:graphicImage name="/demo/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
</p:dialog>

<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" action="#{user.FileDownloadView}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s">
        <p:fileDownload value="#{user.file}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function start() {
    PF('statusDialog').show();
}

function stop() {
    PF('statusDialog').hide();
}
</script>
```

**user.java**

```
private StreamedContent file;
public void FileDownloadView() 
{        

InputStream stream =((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream(".../webapps/project/root/user.xls");
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/xls", "user.xls");
```

}

when I click commandButton status dialog open and hide but download options is not shown. I check log to file the file is present in my webapps folder but file not download. I change command button action to replace actionListener but also not working

Comment: read about using `@PostConstruct` as opposed to using your constructor

Comment: I change to try it but it not working